# How to handle SVG and canvas in pdfmake & html2pdfmake

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas, pdfmake

I am using [html2pdfmake](https://github.com/ymkins/html2pdfmake) to convert a div to pdf. My div contains tables and also contains some svg charts. But i am not getting the svg into the pdf. I tried converting it using base64 but is paste the base64 code into the pdf.

I converted my svg to base64 like :

```
var html = d3.select('#idOfSVG').select("svg").attr("version", 1.1).attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg").node().parentNode.innerHTML;
var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);
var base_image = new Image();
base_image.src = imgsrc;
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.id = 'canvas'
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(base_image,0,0);
```

Then i added the same into the content.

Also when i used `ParseHtml(content,document.getElementById("myPDFDiv"))`

My div `myPDFDiv` gets deleted from the DOM.

Any help will be highly appreciated !!

Comment: A few things : This will taint any canvas in IE<Edge. You **need** to have absolute `width` and `height` attributes set to your root svg node.  To get a string representation of your svg node, it's better to use `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(yourSVGElement)` than adding these attributes like you do. You don't need to base64 it, you can use `'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(yourSVGString)`. And more importantly, **you must wait for the load event of your Image before being able to draw it on the canvas**.

Comment: But none of it explains why you get the b64 string in your pdf... And since I don't know pdfmake, I can't help further.

Comment: @kaido thanks... in pdfmake it iterates all the items and then put it in pdf but they have not supported the SVG or canvas so i am writing custom for SVG , so that i append the base64 of the same into the pdf.

Comment: don't call drawImage till the Image object's onload event has fired.

Comment: I have found out a way to the same. thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **html2pdfmake**, it iterates all the elements in the div and make `JSON` for the same which you can use with **pdfmake**.

You can add SVG support by adding a switch case for `SVG` like :

```
Case 'SVG' : 
 addImage(cnt,e);

function addImage (cnt,e) {
            //Serialize the svg element and then put it in a canvas
//Then update the cnt object
var url = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        cnt.push({image: url,
              width: 200,
              height: 250,
              margin: [ 20, 0, 0, 0 ]
        });


}
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Hi,thanks, i wrote custom code for SVG and NVD3 both as i have to handle but i did almost the same.

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle for the same